# How to add custom button in custom console component of Contact page layout

Tags: publisher-action, custom-console-components

I want to add custom button to left subTab of Publisher action of Contact page.
Can we add custom button in Feed/Publisher View's custom component of Contact?

Answer (score 0):

You can not add buttons to the feed publisher. You need to create an action and associate it the same visualforce page (you can not associate url or javascript to actions).

Notify me if you need more help.

EDIT: if you need buttons on the feed, if the buttons are added to the layout, these button will appear in the feed. Exactly, the buttons will be in the section 8 here: https://help.salesforce.com/resource/HTHelpDocImages_200_5_en_US_2/case_feed_overview.png

Comment: More details about create an object-specific action https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_object_specific_actions.htm